# Distribute derivative of sum with constant term after substitution

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

If I do

```
import sympy
k, V, Vprime = sympy.symbols('k, V, Vprime')

print sympy.diff(k + V(t), t)
```

I get `Derivative(V(t), t)` as I expect - the derivative distributes and the constant term has zero derivative.

However, if I construct an equivalent expression via substitution, `simplify` does not distribute the derivative. How can I get the same result via substitution as when I evaluate the expression directly?

```
sympy.diff(Vprime(t)).subs({Vprime(t): k + V(t)}).simplify()
```

returns `Derivative(k + V(t), t)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is provided by the [doit](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.doit) method, which says it "Evaluate(s) objects that are not evaluated by default like limits, integrals, sums and products.":

```
sympy.diff(Vprime(t)).subs({Vprime(t): k + V(t)}).doit()
```

yields

```
Derivative(V(t), t)
```